# how can we highlight recently opened file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

hello everyone here I am trying to highlight recently opened file.can someone tell me how can i achieve this in Angularjs.Thanks you.

In my scenario i have list of doc file in ng-repeat i am iterating it. facing issue how should i understand which one is recently file opened and how should i high light it,

here is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles" ng-class="{'highlighter-row-Class' : file.id == 1}">
 <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{ file.temporaryId }}</td>
 <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow col-xs-4">
   {{ file.attributes.name }}
 </td>
 <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
 <td class="text-center col-xs-1" ng-class= "{'highlighter-QuickScore' : file.attributes.areQuickScoreFieldsMissing}">{{file.attributes.quickScore}}</td>
 <td class="text-center col-xs-5">
 <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="annotate un-annotated words" data-ng-click="getOrphans($index)">
 <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" ng-show="file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" title="promote to gold standard" data-ng-click="markAsGoldStd(file.attributes.name)">
  <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="delete from corpus" data-ng-click="deleteResume(file.attributes.name)">
   <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
 <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="add to tracker" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isModelHtmlPresent || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected"
                                                    data-ng-click="moveToJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
   <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
   </td>
```

here i am highlighting the file which Id=1 by using ng-class but i want highlight recently opened file ,YOu can see in image my current output,if you have any idea how can i achieve my requirement you can tell me here.

[image]

Comment: what determines what makes a file recently opened and is it all recently opened files or just the last one?

Comment: no file is opened here, you need to click on data-ng-click="getOrphans($index)" button to open file means first button for open a file

Comment: Just one selected file...or any that have been clicked on?

Comment: Basically I'd pass the file object you get from ng-repeat to getOrphans, push its id to an array on the controller and then use ng-class to check if the id of a file is in that array and style accordingly.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, any that have been clicked on.

Comment: @MikeFeltman thanks for your suggestion.